# Extracting file content from office's .BIN format

Tags: c#, ms-office, ole

I'm trying to alter an office file's attachment with C#, for example, I have a PowerPoint file containing a Word Document.

I want to alter the inner document and add 'Hello World' to it.

My problem is that files are always saved as .BIN files which wraps the original file does anyone have experience extracting the original file from a .BIN file format and can help me?

Comment: What are you doing (programmatically) to end up with a "BIN file" ?

Comment: just drag the docx file to an open powerpoint presentation

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code how you extract the Word document from the Powerpoint file. Also you should present the first few bytes of the BIN file in hexadecimal format (magic header).